# jQuery Combining on() and addClass()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a `keydown` event binding that is attached to elements which have the class `numbersOnly` which looks like this:

```
$('.numbersOnly').keydown(function(e) {
    // Determine which key was pressed and ignore if not a number.
});
```

This works on all elements which were added on page load. However, if I add the class to an element dynamically using `.addClass()`, the event does not fire on that element. I've tried changing `.keydown(` to `.on('keydown'`, but it makes no difference (I know it shouldn't - they should be the same).

I'm using jQuery 1.9.1 but I've also tested this in 2.x and it doesn't work there either. Here's a fiddle with a working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/2L5cg/

Comment: Pretty sure there is a duplicate, searching for it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20317092/jquery-after-adding-class-to-a-new-element-cant-trigger-event-by-clicking-on

Comment: Just a note: the difference between jQuery 1.X and 2.X isn't features, it's browser compatibliity

Comment: Thanks, Karl-André. I was searching mostly for the function names (on/addClass) so I hadn't found this answer.

Thanks for the clarification, Ian.

Thanks to Felix Kling as well.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [**delegated event**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) as class is added dynamically:

```
$(document).on('click','.boxClick', function() {
    $('#displayText').show();
});
```

[**UPDATED FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/2hP72/)